# Resizing custom user control according to data in the webBrowser control docked in it

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, custom-controls, webbrowser-control

I have a `webBrowser` control named `webBrowser1` that is added and docked as `DockStyle.Full`  on a custom user control. The web-browser accepts some HTML text dynamically and displays it. I disabled the scroll bars of the `webBrowser` control. My problem is that whenever the content is somewhat lengthy, the `webBrowser` hides it from below. But the requirement of my project objective is that the webBrowser must not show either scroll bars or it should not hide some of the content. The content must be completely shown as it is without scrolling. That means the user control on which the `webBrowser` is docked must resize itself according to `webBrowser`'s content. So, can anyone please suggest me how to achieve this? I searched all over the internet and SO but found nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the current size of HTML window via [WebBrowser.Document.Window.Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlwindow.size.aspx) and resize the container control accordingly. Depending on how your `WebBrowser` control content receives dynamic updates, you'd probably need to do this after each update. You could also try `WebBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle` if `Document.Window.Size` doesn't grow in the expected way.

**[EDITED]** The following code works for me (IE10):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
    this.webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
    this.webBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.None;
    this.webBrowser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.webBrowser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(320, 200);
    DownloadAsync("http://www.example.com").ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
        var html = task.Result;
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format(
            "WebBrowser.Size: {0}, Document.Window.Size: {1}, Document.Body.ScrollRectangle: {2}\n\n{3}",
            this.webBrowser.Size,
            this.webBrowser.Document.Window.Size,
            this.webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Size,
            html));
        this.webBrowser.Size = this.webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Size;
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

async Task<string> DownloadAsync(string url)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> onloadTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler handler = null;

    handler = delegate
    {
        this.webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= handler;

        // attach to subscribe to DOM onload event
        this.webBrowser.Document.Window.AttachEventHandler("onload", delegate
        {
            // each navigation has its own TaskCompletionSource
            if (onloadTcs.Task.IsCompleted)
                return; // this should not be happening
            // signal the completion of the page loading
            onloadTcs.SetResult(true);
        });
    };

    // register DocumentCompleted handler
    this.webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += handler;

    // Navigate to url
    this.webBrowser.Navigate(url);

    // continue upon onload
    await onloadTcs.Task;

    // the document has been fully loaded, can access DOM here

    // return the current HTML snapshot
    return ((dynamic)this.webBrowser.Document.DomDocument).documentElement.outerHTML.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Its showing `NullReferenceException` on both the properties. Even I am already setting the `DocumentText` before this.

Answer (score 1):

To resize your usercontrol you first need to get the size needed by the content. This can be achived with **TextRender.MeasureText**, like so:

```
public static int GetContentHeight(string content, Control contentHolder, Font contentFont)
{     
    Font font = (contentFont != null) ? contentFont : contentHolder.Font;
    Size sz = new Size(contentHolder.Width, int.MaxValue);
    int padding = 3;
    int borders = contentHolder.Height - contentHolder.ClientSize.Height;
    TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;
    sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText(content, contentHolder.Font, sz, flags);
    int cHeight = sz.Height + borders + padding;

    return cHeight;             
}
```

In your case it's a bit more tricky, as the text contains HTML-tags wich needs to be filtered away, to get the correct height.. I belive this can be achived with RegEx or a simple algo wich removes all content between < and > from a string.. You may also have to create special handlig for some HTML-tags (I.E Lists)

Comment: I can't remove HTML text as `<br/>` and other tags which introduces newline will change height. Also your function is returning 23 length for any content I add.