# WebBrowser Madness

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, uri, drawtobitmap

**Edit:** The original question was a long one with many wild guesses. I have cut it back to the remaining mysteries..

I've been struggling and puzzling all day now and guess I ought to present my problem to the community.

It originated from the post called [Screenshot method generates black images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331011/screenshot-method-generates-black-images/24332354#24332354).  The original poster wants to continuously take screenshots of his program, which includes a WebBrowser, every n seconds **even when the user is logged off**.

When the user is logged out he has no screen anymore. Therefore any attempt to read the screen will fail. If using a window handle the result is a black box, when using CopyFromScreen a GDI-error exception.

But the program window is still there and using `DrawToBitmap` works fine even when the user is logged out.

Here are the conditions and the remaining issues:

- The user must not touch/click the `WebBrowser` in any way. If he does by, say, Scrolling, Clicking, Navigating the subsqeuent `DrawToBitmap` calls result in an empty box.
- While the `WebBrowser` remains untouched, it is enough to do a `Refresh` before the next DrawToBitmap call.
- After touching it it is neccessary to load the URL again by doing a  `webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(URLpath);`
- When navigating the new URL must be stored to do this. I do that in the Navigated event.
- No matter what, `DrawToBitmap` fails (with the empty box) if the webpage contains a `<input type="text" ..> field`.
- By vandalising the `DocumentText` with a `Replace("<input", "<in_put");` this could be healed, but without further tricks this will lose the CSS sheets..

To test it throw two `Buttons, a Label, a Timer, a Combobox and a WebBrowser on a Form` and copy the code; change the filepath to a folder that fits your setup and watch..:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
    this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
    this.button1.Text = "Start";
    this.button2.Text = "Stop";
    this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
    this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions",
        "http://webcam.zirndorf.de/marktplatz/gross.jpg"});
    scapeRect = this.ClientRectangle;
    webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com/questions");
    this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += 
                   new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);

}

Rectangle scapeRect = Rectangle.Empty;
int imgIndex = 0;
int urlIndex = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = 10 * 1000;  // every 10 seconds
    timer1.Start();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
}


private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imgIndex ++;
    label1.Text = imgIndex .ToString();
    webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(comboBox1.Text); // this works almost always
    //webBrowser1.Refresh();                   // this works only if the WB is 'untouched'   
    string filename = "d:\\scrape\\AB_sos_Screen" + imgIndex .ToString("000") + ".png";
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(scapeRect.Width, scapeRect.Height);
    this.DrawToBitmap(bmp, scapeRect);
    bmp.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    bmp.Dispose();
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.Text != "") webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(comboBox1.Text);
}




private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!comboBox1.Items.Contains(e.Url.ToString()))
        urlIndex = comboBox1.Items.Add(e.Url.ToString());
    else
        urlIndex = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(e.Url.ToString());
    if (urlIndex >= 0) comboBox1.SelectedIndex = urlIndex;
    button1.Focus();
}
```

I can now navigate almost freely and the screen scraping keeps working - except for pages with textual input fields like e.g. the **Users** or the **Tags** pages.

I wonder if anybdoy can reproduce ..?

Or explain??

Or have I been just 'ghost hunting' after all and the thing is simply unreliable???

**Final Edit:**

While it would have been nice to get an explanation, getting a working solution probably has to be good enough.. The OP has found code that uses a `PrintWindow` call to `user32.dll` and solves all problems. It works while being logged off, works with `Refreshing` even after clicking in the `WebBrowser` and scrapes all pages, including those with textual input fields.  Here is my version of it:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
//...
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, uint nFlags);

public Bitmap CaptureControl(Control ctl)
{
    //Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ctl.Width, ctl.Height);  // includes borders
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ctl.ClientRectangle.Width, ctl.ClientRectangle.Height);  // content only
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        IntPtr hDC = graphics.GetHdc();
        try      { PrintWindow(ctl.Handle, hDC, (uint)0);   }
        finally  { graphics.ReleaseHdc(hDC);                }
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

This can capture a Form or a Control with or without Borders.

Comment: You may want to the following approach, I think it should work with your scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21828265/1768303

Comment: @Noseratio: thanks, interesting post. however the problems at hand were solved by using `PrintWindow´, see edit!

Comment: TaW, I noticed your edit after I posted the comment. In my solution I use `OleDraw` for that, apparently it better respects some CSS rules.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Screenshot method generates black images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331011/screenshot-method-generates-black-images)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add my experience, after a long day of beating my head against this problem.

The above `PrintWindow`-based method just drew a black rectangle over most of the `WebBrowser` control, though oddly, the last few lines of displayed text seemed to come through. So even the black rectangle is inconsistent! But I was able to get `DrawToBitmap()` to work.

However, there are all sorts of hidden requirements.

- First, you can only have one `WebBrowser` control in your form
  — when I tried to add a second one, it would display fine, but
  it would come out blank when drawn to a bitmap.
- Second, the `WebBrowser` has to be the topmost control in your form,
  and it can't have any top/bottom margins applied to it.  Violating
  this tended to lead to the bottom of my displayed HTML getting cut
  off, and large-enough top/bottom margins tended to lead to the page's
  content getting vertically stretched, when drawn to bitmap.
- Third, to keep the `WebBrowser` from getting touched, create a
  disabled `Control` to wrap it, and put the `WebBrowser` inside of
  that control (with a `Dock` of `Fill`).  You'll have to deal with
  displaying the contents of the entire HTML document, most of which is
  covered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818089/) (i.e. set your web-browser, and containing
  control's size to the web-browser's `Document.Body.ScrollRectangle`
  in a `DocumentCompleted` event-handler).

But so far, this method is working consistently for me.